# can $Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails be generated dynamically?

Tags: apex, customer-community

I am going to disable to 'Welcome email' and write a workflow on User which triggers an email alert with the VF email template.

I tried using the field $Network.NetworkUrlForUserEmails in VF email template but it comes as blank.

It is specifically mentioned this field is only available in VF communities templates. Is there a way I can generate this through Apex?